# XPath to count elements and compare the count to an integer (XSD 1.1)?

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, assert, xsd-1.1

Here's a sketch of my XML file:

```xml
<file recordCount="n">
    <record/>
    <record/>
    <record/> <!-- ...etc... -->
</file>
```

I made the XML Schema (version 1.1) **assert on the `file` element** that the `@recordCount` (a positive integer) must equal the calculated number of `record` elements contained in `file`.

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
test="count(record) eq @recordCount"
```

This is currently **failing** the test XML file whatever I put in `@recordCount` (given a `nonZeroInteger`) and however many (valid) `record` elements I have...

I assume I'm missing something really basic here like a node path or the type of the 2 variables to compare in the `test`?

Possibly related: [XSD 1.1 Assert to Count and Compare Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595561/xsd-1-1-assert-to-count-and-compare-elements)

Comment: I suspect you've made some really simple mistake, like (a) putting the assertion on the wrong element, or (b) forgetting to use namespace prefixes in your XPath expression. I would suggest also doing an explicit conversion of recordCount to xs:integer, though I'm not sure that's essential (it depends how recordCount is declared). If you reduced it to a simple but executable example, we could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks - I fixed it somehow. I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath is correct. It's now behaving as expected in the IDE. If I learn why it was not validating correctly I'll update the question.